Incognito Navigation with multiple devices
Suppose I have a Windows PC and an Android phone. The PC is connected to the phone's hotspot. I am logged into Microsoft Edge with the same account on both the phone and the computer. If I activate incognito mode on the phone and start browsing, will it be possible for other people in the future who have only the PC and not the phone to
acquire the browsing data related to the time PC and phone were connected through targeted procedures?
